# How to forward external port to Kali Linux?

Tags: networking, kali-linux, router, port-forwarding

I have an issue about networking. My previous question was about how does metasploit payload work? And I got right answer( I have to redirect port to internal ip which corresponds to Kali Linux's ip). You can access it from this url.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/87399/how-does-metasploits-payload-work-with-a-remote-target

However, after several tries I didn't get what I want.So, problem is:
My router is TPlink TL-WR842N and I'm currently using Vmware Player, but my router's and Vmware's subnet are different , so I couldn't redirect due to this.

[image: Port redirection in Virtual Server options]

VmWare is using 192.168.29.1 and subnet mask 255.255.255.0
My routers conf is 192.168.1.1 and subnet mask 255.255.255.0

So, friends, how to redirect external 4444 port to Kali linux with ip 192.168.29.131 ?

Comment: What is the network configuration of your VM? Did you try bridged mode?

Comment: Bro i have also tried bridged mode and i was unsuccesful :(

Comment: I'm not really sure to understand your problem, why don't you just put the VM and the router in the same subnet? Or do you have trouble forwarding ports with your specific router?

Comment: @Dillinur i think it is router specific problem :(

Comment: Its about vmware, not about information security.